# Is there a way to record what you do in Sketchup as Ruby script?

Tags: ruby, macros, sketchup

I am currently working on designing my own plugin in Sketchup using the Ruby API. I was wondering whether there was any tool/extension that would allow me to record whatever I do in the program as a Ruby macro so that it would make it much easier to produce code to recreate exactly what I want. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that the SketchUp Ruby API doesn't provide enough insight to the application internals to know exactly what is going on.

You could probably use observer to detect entity creating, modification, deleting - but I am not sure how you would easily reuse it other than creating exactly what you just created.